# Yahoo Finance API like chart

Tags: charts

I want to create a chart very similar to [yahoo Finance interactive chart](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=%5EDJI#chart1:symbol=%5Edji;range=6m;indicator=volume;charttype=line;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined) in a .NET application. The interactive chart on Yahoo finance is not included in their developer API. Has anyone tried to leverage their API to create a similar chart? Although the chart is very much like the one used on Yahoo, the data used for my analysis is not Stock data. So, I will not be able to call the Yahoo Url by feeding any query params.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your finance.yahoo.com link is not rendering. You might want to try to use a tinyurl.

Comment: I modified the Url to use a Tiny Url. Any thoughts?

Comment: can we use yahoo finance API using nodeJS and JavaScript instead of .NET?

Answer (score 4):

If your looking at a web based chart, the *flot* graphs for jQuery are a good option IMHO. They look pretty schnazzy, are interactive and are very simple to get working.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/flot

Comment: I didnt know about this plugin for jQuery, I will take a peek.

Answer (score 2):

amCharts [Stock chart](http://amcharts.com/stock/) is of the same breed. It's Flash based but you can easily use it with any server side engine. Not sure whether you are looking for web or windows solution though.

Comment: I saw amCharts but am looking at Silverlight to build something similar. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: amCharts has JavaScript version of Stock chart now.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [Infragistics Web Charts](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/webchart.aspx) also.