# Getting stock graphs

Tags: java, yahoo, yahoo-finance

Is it possible to get the **stock graphs** of a particular company from yahoo finance in java. I know how to get the stock quotes but i dont know how to get the graphs. Does yahoo provide this service at all or is there some other api which i have to use. The stocks symbol list belong to bse and nse(national stock exchange of India).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, they don't provide a way for you to get the graphs themselves. You will have to build the graph on your own using the data exposed by the existing API.

If you're looking for a similar look and feel to the Yahoo Interactive Charts, this question on Stack Overflow is relevant - [Yahoo Finance API like chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534650/yahoo-finance-api-like-chart)

Comment: But the data provided by their existing api is not  sufficient to build a complete stock graph. Working within this limitation how would i create charts from this data using  java. Do you know of any good tutorial which explains this.

Comment: This is the best I could find which explains building a stock graph in quite a lot of detail - http://greatwebguy.com/programming/java/stock-quote-and-chart-from-yahoo-in-java/